# Collating data based on a parameter in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following type of data:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
heyA  123  ABC
heyB  456  VCV
heyA  123  SDF
heyA  123  ABC
```

I want to collate them such that

The output should be:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
heyA 123  ABC,SDF
heyB 456  VCV
```

Please suggest me ways of doing this. Thanks a lot in advance!

I have tried:

```
for i in Col1:
  for k in Col1:
    if i==k:
      //dosome
    else:
      //dosomethingelse
```

but this isnt giving me the desired result. It is matching the same entry with itself and hence, the incorrect result.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: I am new to python, so I couldnt just figure out what would the most convenient way of doing this.

Comment: So what's the inconvenient way you figured out? For you it's pretty convenient for someone else to write it, but that's not what SO's for.

Comment: I have tried this:
for i in col1:
    
    for k in col1:
       
        if i==k :
            //dosomething
            else:
                //doother

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I have edited the question.

Comment: *"this isnt giving me the desired result"* - then what **is** it giving you? For what input? Errors? Then provide the traceback. Unexpected outputs? Then provide the actual outputs. Give a [mcve], not a vague description. I'd strongly recommend you spend some time in the [help] per the links above.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you please point to me any links which may be helpful here?

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, I assume that you're a beginner in python. So, my answer here will be boring to the pros.

First, you need to install `pandas` which is a cool python module that deals with datasets.

Second, you need to custom your data points and make them look like the following dictionary (*I will leave this part to you*):

```
d = {"Col1": ["heyA", "heyB", "heyA", "heyA"], 
     "Col2": [123, 456, 123, 123], 
     "Col3": ["ABC", "VCV", "SDF", "ABC"]}
```

Now, the fun part begins!

We will use a function from `pandas` module, this function is called `group_by()`. This function groups the data based on a specified column values. So, let's try it out and group our data accoring to the first two columns which are `Col1` and `Col2`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> grouped = df.groupby( ["Col1", "Col2"] )
>>> grouped
<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x000000000AB9A6A0>   
>>> grouped.groups
{('heyA', 123L): Int64Index([0, 2, 3], dtype='int64'), 
('heyB', 456L): Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')}
```

As you can see, now we have two groups `('heyA', 123L)` and `('heyB', 456L)`.

Now, let's use the `groupby` object and apply a function to it, we will apply the `set` casting to remove duplicated values. Then, we will use the function `reset_index()` to reset the indices.

```
>>> grouped['Col3'].apply(set).reset_index()
   Col1  Col2        Col3
0  heyA   123  {SDF, ABC}
1  heyB   456       {VCV}
```

If you're concerned about the {} brackets, you can run the following line instead:

```
>>> grouped['Col3'].apply(set).apply(list).reset_index()
   Col1  Col2        Col3
0  heyA   123  [SDF, ABC]
1  heyB   456       [VCV]
```